# why django does not find the url?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django, and I'm trying to access the following web page by clicking on "dataset celiac" and acces so to "celiac.html". On the html side, here is my code which corresponds to this part of the page where I click on "dataset celiac":

```
<div class="visit"><a href="celiac.html">dataset celiac</a></div>
```

Then, on the views.py side, here is the code corresponding to the view which is supposed to return the html page to celiac.html:

```
def CeliacView(request):
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = forms.CeliacForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        columns = form.cleaned_data['columns']
        algo = form.cleaned_data['algo']
        if algo == "Logistic regression" and columns == 'CDR3_IMGT':
            return render(request, 'data/cdr3.html', locals())
else:
    tableData = get_table_data_to_representation()
    context = {'form': forms.CeliacForm(), 'tableData': tableData}
    return render(request, 'data/celiac.html', context)
```

And regarding the urls.py file here is my code:

```
app_name = 'data'
urlpatterns = [
path('datasets/', views.SetView, name='datasets'),
path('celiac/', views.CeliacView, name='celiac'),
]
```

Finally, here is what django shows me when I click on celiac dataset: [Page not found (404)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqqVZ.jpg)

Can someone tell me what could be the problem here please? why django does not find the correct url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your href shouldn't be the filename, put the path where your url points you towards. For making it more dynamic, I'd suggest using the url tag. Like so:

```
<div class="visit"><a href="{% url 'data:celiac' %}">dataset celiac</a></div>
```

Comment: i changed my code as you told me , but i still have this error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1iL6.jpg , What could be the problem pls ? i Searched myself but i did not find the solution

Comment: I updated my answer. Considering that it's in an app, you need the prefix of <app_name>: